# Google reCAPTCHA Invisible working but not Invisible

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

I've implemented the invisible reCAPTCHA and it's all working fine, but Google in their wisdom add a terms/privacy box as an overlay on the bottom right side of the screen:

[image]

Unfortunately because I already have a schedule box there it looks a mess.  Both Google and my scheduler are external code so I feel like I don't have control.  Is there anyway to block/change sides etc the Google terms.

Comment: Are you able to share some code please?

Comment: The code is just the standard code from https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible I have made no changes to styles etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this, although it doesn't give much control:

[g-recaptcha tag attributes and grecaptcha.render parameters](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#config)

If you add:

```
data-badge="bottomleft"
```

or

```
data-badge="inline"
```

It allows you to flip sides or put it in the form.  In my opinion Google needs to address this, I'd happily have a link to all their privacy/terms but this encroaches massively on my site..